How to programmatically interact with Visual Studio
Is there an API to interact with Visual Studio programmatically.

I'm trying to automate a repetitive task.
I have a solution with about 500 projects added (mostly .csprojs). About 100 of those projects are loaded.
About 50 of the projects are in directory foo or its subdirectories -- other projects are in various other directories.
For each project, proj in directory foo and its subdirectories, I need to do the following
In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project file, select "Build Dependencies", select "Project Dependencies"

This opens up a "Project Dependencies" window for the project (the current selection in the "Projects" drop-down) and the project's direct and indirect dependencies listed under "Depends On:". Each dependency is listed next to a check-box. For each project in foo, I need the list of dependencies whose check-box is checked.
(If curious, I have gotten my solution into a state where only the projects in foo and their direct dependencies are loaded -- and what I'm doing with these steps is: for each project in foo, get the list of its direct dependencies.)

If there's a way to do this programmatically, it'd save me a lot of manual, repetitive work now.

Used the keyboard shortcuts menu to find a list of VS commands that have "dependenc" in their name.

And in fact, if a project file is selected in Solution Explorer, then running the Project.ProjectDependencies command from the Command Window does open up
the corresponding "Project Dependencies" window.
Didn't find relevant results when I searched web for Project.ProjectDependencies. Typing help Project.ProjectDependencies and help Project into VS's Command Window wasn't informative.
Neither of the following worked when I did them in the Command Window:

Project.ProjectDependencies <path-to-csproj>
Project.ProjectDependencies <path-to-dir-containing-csproj>


I also looked thru several docs on VS commands

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-window?view=vs-2022


Just found out about EnvDTE. Would appreciate some guidance on it.

Information about the project is stored in files. It'd be easier to read the files directly instead of trying to automate the UI.

@tkausl If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting to search .csproj contents for <ProjectReference Include="([^"]+)" .> and extract direct project deps that way? Definitely worth looking into! In general, though, I'd like to learn to interact w/ VS programmatically in case it's useful in the future.

BuildDependencies Interface inside EnvDTE may help you however it would be easier to look through project files to show all dependencies.

@tkausl and @Amadeusz, I ended up using dotnet list reference in a PowerShell script
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78814190/13881506
